# a cylindrical tank question with diff equations

Tags: calculus

we hae a cylindrical tank which is full and depth is 10 meters. The rate at which the depth of liquid drops is proportional to the square root of the depth of the liquid. After draining for 20 minutes, the tank has now depth 5 meters. How long it takes for tank to empty?

attempt:

Let $H(t)$ be the height of the tank. We know $H(0)=10$ an $H(20)=5$. Also, since

$$ H' = \sqrt{H} \implies \int \frac{ \mathrm{d} H }{\sqrt{H}} = \int \mathrm{d} t \implies 2 \sqrt{H} = t + C$$

So, $2 \sqrt{5} = 20+ C $ so $C = 2 \sqrt{5}-20$. Thus,

$$ \sqrt{H} = \frac{t}{2} + \sqrt{5} - 10  $$

so, $H=0$ if $ t = \dfrac{ 10 - \sqrt{5} }{2} $

is this correct?

Comment: I think $H(20)$ is known! not $H(30)$

Comment: As time increases, height **decreses**. Does your equation of $H$ and $t$ say so?

Comment: Always ask yourself whether the answer could possibly be true. In this case your answer, $\frac{10-\sqrt{5}}{2}$, is a little less than $4$, so you would be claiming that the tank empties in less than four minutes, although the problem statement says it takes $20$ minutes to drop to $10$ meters. Clearly the answer is wrong. The correct answer must be greater than $20$; since the rate of drainage is slowing down, moreover, the answer should be greater than $40$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{dH}{dt} = k\sqrt{H} \implies \int \frac{ \mathrm{d} H }{\sqrt{H}} = \int k ~\mathrm{d} t \implies 2 \sqrt{H} = kt + C$$

$H(0)=10$ and $H(20)=5$

$$ C=2\sqrt{10}~~ k=\frac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{10}}{10}$$

Hence $$ 2\sqrt{H} = \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{10}}{10}\right)t+2\sqrt{10}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow H= \left(\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{10}}{20}\right)t+\sqrt{10} \right)^2 $$

At $H=0$ $\implies$ $t=20\sqrt{2}+40$

Answer (score 0):

I would say no.

The question says the rate of fall in liquid level is proportional to $√H$ and not equal to.

SO you should take $dh/dt=-k√h$.
Then integrate this equation with the limits for h as 10 to h and for t as 0 to t.
You will get $2(√h -√10)=-kt$.   ----(1)

Now put $t=20$ and $h=5$ in this equation to get the value of k.
Then simply substitute this value of k in equation(1) and put $h=0$ to get the value of t.

Also, please correct your question, in description you said time taken for height to reduce to 5m was 20mins but you had put 30mins everywhere in the solution